# How to display multiple rows in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am Sirisha. I am new to developing for iPhone. I want to display multiple rows in a table view (Ex: One   10, Two 15, etc.) Please help me.

Comment: i think you meant "multiple columns" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can do this by using section of table 1st section contain 10 2nd section contain 15

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;       //one section in the table.
}
```

and then use this method to add number of rows

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
        //number of rows in the section
```

if section 1 then 
return 10
if section 2
return 15

Comment: You could get started with example code of UITableView.                         http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/03/uitableview-drill-down-table-view.html                                                                                http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-1-uitableview-using-nsarray/

Answer (score 0):

in view did load should allocate a array for row array
rowArray = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

  return 1;
  }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [rowArray count];

}

It will return 3 rows with 1 section in a table view